# File download only returns a file with [Object Object] as content

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a select box where I provide download links to all PDFfiles in a users' directory. By clicking an option, a download should be triggered:

**Razor page:**

```
<td>
   <select @onchange="@((e) => DownloadFile(e))">
   <option disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
   @foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
      "\\\\my.server\\Application\\Data\\",
      "*",
      SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
      {
      <option value="@file">@TrimFilePath(@file, Convert.ToString(@user.PkId))</option>
      }

   </select>

</td>
<td>

        @code
        {
            public async void DownloadFile(ChangeEventArgs e)
                {
                    string file = e.Value.ToString();

                    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
                    "FileSaveAs",
                    file.Split('\\').Last(),
                    await Http.GetAsync("api/UserManagement?FileName="+file)
                    );
                }
        }
```

The DownloadFile methods makes a Web API call to my **controller**:

```
namespace UserManagement.Controller
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserManagementController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Get: api/UserManagement
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(string FileName)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);        

            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        }
    }
}
```

After the controller returns the File object, the InvokeAsync method of the razor page invokes the Javascript to initiate the download:

**Javascript:**

```
function FileSaveAs(filename, fileContent) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = filename;
    link.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContent)
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

The problem is that the files that I get only have the following content inside:

[object Object]

When I use Postman to call the API with the filepath as parameter, I get a proper response with my PDF file.

Trying to debug this error, I learned that the File object in my Controller is OK with the byte[] having the same size as my file.

But when I have a look at the Javascript, here is the problem: the fileContent gives me a statusCode 500 and the link.href value is

> "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%5Bobject%20Object%5D"

I also tried to bind an `<a>` element to the option, but that did not work:

```
<select>
  <option disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
  @foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
  "\\\\company.local\\Application\\Data\\" +
  @user.PkId, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
  {
    <option value="@file">
      <a href="@file">@TrimFilePath(@file, Convert.ToString(@user.PkId))</a>
    </option>
  }
</select>;
```

Comment: Why don't you bind a `<a` list : `<option value="@file"><a href="@GetFileUrl(file)"> @TrimFilePath(@file, Convert.ToString(@user.PkId))</a></option>` ?

Comment: You write `razor page` but you probably mean `razor component` - those two are different things.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's a razor component.

Comment: @agua from mars: I did not know this construct so far. What's the benefit? Is it supposed to open the address directly without the DownloadFile routine?

Comment: Exactly, let the browser do its job.

Comment: OK, well it does not do anything when I click a select. Have added this possible solution to my initial question.

Comment: But back to my original solution. I have changed this line:

await Http.GetAsync("api/UserManagement?FileName="+file)

to this:

Http.GetAsync("api/UserManagement?FileName="+file).Result

And now at least my result in the Javascript gives me status code 200. But the download is still only couple of bytes with [Object Object] as plain text in the PDF file.